# wpf cannot locate Resource ( User Control Image)

Tags: c#, wpf

i already read many solution in this community.
but not helped resolved my problem.

my problem is imagebrush in usercontrol not visible to design time. but visible to runtime.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzurX.png)

error message : cannot locate Resource

Source :

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Image/NextDay.png"/>
<!--<ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Main;Image/NextDay.png"/>-->
```

i tried this. but not working. maybe Exist another solution...
please Comment me.

add : image build option is Resource.

Comment: You'll have to provide more details. That's an ImageBrush not an Image. How are you using it? And what build options is the image set to?

Comment: modifyed. build option is resource.

Comment: and I used to image brush in rectangle. @MarkFeldman

Comment: If it works at runtime, you have apparently done everything right. If the XAML Designer can't find the resource, try to rebuild the solution or restart Visual Studio.

Comment: i tried this. but it is same. @Clemens

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with the same issue, this worked for me.

The image you need to use in your UserControl must be set with `BuildAction` = *Resource* in its property. To do so, select your image in Solution Explorer, press F4 to open property tab.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to specify the pack and application. You can try specifying only the path like this.

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="Image\NextDay.png"/>
```

For more reference

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/painting-with-images-drawings-and-visuals?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: comment thank you. but this solution is not working... please read my content again.

Comment: Can you kindly update the complete code along with usercontrol where you set the background. So we can try ourselves @HebenVariuf

Comment: "*You don't need to specify the pack and application. You are required to specify only the path*" - this is plain wrong. While you may omit the URI prefix, it is not wrong to specify it explicitly. This post makes no sense.

Comment: @Clemens. I just suggested to omit the url prefix. I didn't say "it is not wrong to specify it explicitly".

Comment: Read your post. You said "*You are required to specify only the path*". Even if you only meant to suggest to omit the prefix, how exactly should that be a solution?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).